# What are Gradle dependency configurations?

Tags: gradle

Could somebody please explain in more details (preferably with some real-life examples) what dependency configurations are in Gradle?

For example, let's assume I have:

- `compile group: 'org.foo', name: 'commons-lang', version: '1.2.3', configuration: 'runtime'`
- `testCompile group: 'org.foo', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4.1', configuration: 'testing'`

I was under the impression that `compile` and `testCompile` are the configurations. If so, then what's the `configuration: 'testing'` part for?

Answer (score 0):

These are build configuration names of artifacts... they act just alike when passing a build configuration name to a referenced project, except that these packages always carry the one configuration name they were built with - while projects may have several, resulting in several artifacts.

Comment: I feel retardedly stupid, given the fact that (I believe) I know Maven so well. Would you mind further explaining and illustrating what you mean by this? My understanding is that these are something like scopes (in Maven), but then I'm not sure what to make of the extra `configuration:` bit. Thanks! :)